# Renaming SQL Server Table columns,constraints

Tags: sql, sql-server

We have a table called Patients and we need to rename it to Clients.

All the columns in the table should be renamed to Client as well. For example PatientFirstName will be ClientFirstName.

The column PatientId references around 400 other tables. Sp_Rename will work but it consumes much time. Is there a way to do it faster?

Comment: No, `sp_rename` is the tool to rename things. If you need to rename that many things, perhaps you should reconsider the need to rename them.

Comment: you could make a sql file backup, not a bak file and open it on a editor, but that will only work, if the sql file can be opened. but linux has some tools to handle that kind of thing like https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-use-sed-to-find-and-replace-text-in-files-in-linux-unix-shell/

Comment: You may really want to reconsider changing object names, it's going to be a real fun time locating all of the places within the databases, and the application code where that's going to be a breaking change :)

Comment: You can run multiple threads that each takes one table at a time perhaps to parallelize this